# Stochastic multiple Ito integrals in higher order Milstein schemes (>1)

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-integrals

In the series expansion to obtain the form of higher order Milstein schemes you need to evaluate these two sister integrals (where W_t is the Wiener process):
$$
\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}dW_u\int_{t_i}^{u}ds\\
\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}du\int_{t_i}^{u}dW_s,
$$
after I evaluate the innermost integral I obtain respectively:
$$
\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}dW_u(u-t_i)\\
\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}du (W_u-W_{t_i}).
$$
However I find myself stuck at this point since I cannot explicitly integrate the Wiener process under $du$ and vice-versa $u$ under $dW_u$.
How can I solve these two integrals?

P.S. I was able to solve for the sum of the two integrals
$$
\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}dW_u\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}ds+\int_{u}^{t_{i+1}}du\int_{t_i}^{u}dW_s=(t_{i+1}-t_i)^{3/2}\zeta;
$$
where $\zeta$ is a Gaussian random variable however I could not use this result in any way.

P.P.S Do you have any good references for these kind of integrals? I am basing my question on the second chapter of the Kloeden&Platten book but they provide little insight on the calculation.

Comment: I'd start by substituting $v=u-t_i$ and $B_v=W_u-W_{t_i}$.  Running through everything, this change-of-variable lets you rewrite the integrals as $$\int_0^{\Delta t}v\,\mathrm{d}B_v \\ \int_0^{\Delta t}B_v\,\mathrm{d}v$$ where $\Delta t := t_{i+1}-t_i$.  It doesn't change the underlying question, but it simplifies the notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a numerical solver all you need to know are the variances of those sister integrals and their covariance. From the Ito isometry we get
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\mathbb E\Big[\Big(\textstyle\int_a^bu-a\,dW_u\Big)^2\Big]=\int_a^b(u-a)^2\,du=\frac{(b-a)^3}{3}\,.
\end{align}
Next, using integration-by-parts,
\begin{align}\tag{2}
\textstyle\int_a^b W_udu&=-\textstyle\int_a^bu\,dW_u+b\,W_b-a\,W_a
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\textstyle\int_a^b W_u-W_a\,du&=-\textstyle\int_a^bu\,dW_u+b\,W_b-\cancel{a\,W_a}-b\,W_a+\cancel{a\,W_a}\\[2mm]
&=\textstyle\int_a^bb-u\,dW_u\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}
Similarly to (1) the variance of this is
$$\tag{4}
\mathbb E\Big[\Big(\textstyle\int_a^bb-u\,dW_u\Big)^2\Big]=\int_a^b(b-u)^2\,du=\frac{(b-a)^3}{3}\,.
$$

The covariance is
\begin{align}\tag{5}
\mathbb E\Big[\Big(\textstyle\int_a^bu-a\,dW_u\Big)\Big(\textstyle\int_a^bb-u\,dW_u\Big)\Big]=\int_a^b(u-a)(b-u)\,du=\textstyle\frac{(b-a)^3}{6}\,.
\end{align}

- Sanity check:
  The sum of those integrals should therefore have variance
  $(b-a)^3$ which looks consistent
  with the formula where your $\zeta$ pops up.

The standard reference is Kloeden & Platen, *Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations.*

Comment: What do you exactly mean with: "In a numerical solver all you need to know are the variances of those sister integrals and their covariance."?

Comment: @apelle I rather refer you to the book I mentioned otherwise we might repeat a lot of stuff here that is known. Let's forget about that first sentence. Given your attempt in OP were my formulas (1), (4), (5) helpful ?

Comment: Not really. The problem is not the use and meaning of the Ito isometry. But how does it connect to the result I am looking for. In an other book (I do not remember the title right now) I found that the solution of the two integrals should be  $\Delta t^{3/2}(\zeta\pm\epsilon/\sqrt{3})$ with $\zeta$ and $\epsilon$ two independent gaussian random variables. Where is the connection?

Comment: @apelle You better find out that other book then and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I think I see where the misunderstanding comes from. Basically you are saying it is enough to consider that those integrals represent Gaussian random variable with mean 0 and variance as you wrote and just use this result in your simulation. I was asking something more on the lines of how to evaluate explicitly these two integrals. Badly written question probably. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @apelle As we know, these integrals cannot really be evaluated explicitly. And yes, I just meant to find the  Gaussians and use them in the simulation. The question was not that badly written.